# Inserting multiple rows using SQL - issue with manually incrementing numbers

Tags: sql, insert

Someone else designed this table and I am not allowed to modify it so bear with me.

I am trying to insert multiple rows from one table into another. The table where I am inserting the rows has an ID but it does not auto-increment. I cannot figure out how to manually increment the id as I insert rows. The current code throws an error:

> Error running query. Page15.CaseSerial is invalid in the select list
>   becauseit is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

I've tried adding a GROUP BY clause with no success.

Here's the code:

```
insert into page4 (serial, caseserial, linkserial, type, add1, add2, city, state, orgname, prefername, email, firstname, lastname, salutation, contactstatus, workphone, notes, cellphone, nametype, homephone, fax, zip, payments) 
   select id = max(serial), caseserial, linkserial, type, add1, add2, city, state, 
          orgname, prefername, email, firstname, lastname, salutation, contactstatus, 
          workphone, notes, cellphone, nametype, homephone, fax, zip, payments 
   from page16
```

It would be nice if I could write something to get the highest id from page4 and insert the next highest.

Thanks!

Comment: Which flavour of SQL? The solution will be different depending on what RDBMs you are using

Comment: What kind of server or environment are you using for your database? I am asking because MS Access, for example, supports DMin() and DMax() look-up functions in SQL queries. If your server support user-defined scalar functions you might want to implement those for your convenience and use them in your SQL query.

Comment: This is an article on microsofts approach to this if an MSFT db. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/273586

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @maxId int

select @maxId = max(yourIdColumn)
from YourTable

set @maxId = @maxId + 1

insert into YourTable (yourIdColumn, ....)
values (@maxId, ....)
```

*Disclaimer: not sure how this would transpose over to other RDBMS's, but this is with SQL Server in mind.  Also, this handles inserting only one value.  If you need to insert a set of values, then please let me know.*

Comment: "I am trying to insert multiple rows from one table into another."  He let us know :D

Comment: @xQbert That is true!  Thanks for pointing out (the obvious). ;)  I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: I'm glad you took that in the spirit in which it was meant. Not snide, crude or rude.  I was looking how to do this myself and your approach seemed reasonable. (I was hoping to avoid a cursor but I just can't figure it out without one.)  thus I think that was the approach this (your response) would go. and didn't spend more time on it.  + I wanted to know what RDBMS they were using.